# Django how to select with less queries in a many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models,

```
class TblMaterials(models.Model):
name = ...
....

class TblCategoris(models.Model):
name = ...
....

class TblMaterialCategories(models.Model):
    tbl_categories = models.ForeignKey(TblCategories, blank=True, null=True)
    tbl_materials = models.ForeignKey('TblMaterials', blank=True, null=True)
```

and in my home page i want to print all the materials and related material category within. Obviously there could be some materials without any categories.

in my view i try something like:

```
TblMaterials.objects.all().select_related('tblmaterialcategories_set')
```

and in templates:

```
{%for mat in materials%}
    {{mat.name }}

    {%for cat in mat.tblmaterialcategories_set.all %}
         {{cat.tbl_categories.name}} ,
    {%endfor%}

{%endfor%}
```

I dont think select_related works in that _set item.
I want to achieve something like that without making queries for each item. If I can add another field to material query set and access it like mat.categories and for loop in it, it is also appriciated.

What could be the best way to display all materials and their categories?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `prefetch_related`, not `select_related`.

Answer (score 0):

Select related can be used for the foreign keys which are in the current model. For an example:

class TblMaterials(models.Model):
name = ...
....
Foreign Key: TblMaterialCategories

While calling the TblMaterial model , if you want to use select related with TblMaterialCategories

TblMaterials.objects.all().select_related('tblmaterialcategories')

It will work.